# Which nichrome wire would use to recoil this heater element

Tags: replacement

[image: unspecified device]

I need to re-coil this. Which nichrome wire would you use?

This is a fan speed controller. For perspective the place width is about an inch and there are two plates with about 15 winds each. This will be running in Malaysia using the Brit 220-240 volts A/C mains power. A table fan motor is the only thing to be powered. Sadly no rating on it so a wild card. I've had a bit of a mess around with vaping nichrome could and can get a foot coil going BUT I sense this wont work as it runs hot just on 9V.

Comment: This should be part of your question, not a comment! Please **Edit** your question to include this crucial information.

Comment: Adding heater to a cooling fan is a little contradictory (lol) Can you use a triac dimmer?

Comment: Consider using high power resistors instead.

Comment: This question is completely clear. Would those who consider otherwise please advice why.

Comment: As Reroute says (in different words) | - Find a long partial; portion of the element that is complete. - Work out what %age of the total length it was and measure its resistance. -Total required resistance = Rmeasured x 100 / %_of_length. Wire from a bar heater or toaster should work. How old is it? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Measure the existing damaged coil halves to find the total resistance,

Straighten out a half winding to determine the length of each half turn, use that to work backwards to the exact diameter of wire used

Count how many turns per half to work out how your going to have to recreate the spiral, your looking for a rod equal to the inner diameter, wind on tight enough to deform into the shape but not so tight it does not spring back a tiny amount or you will not be able to remove the forming rod afterwards, I would also think you will need to form it in segments about a full or half turn at a time.